# Unable to create a constant value of type '<Some type>' when using a local variable in linq query, but works with a hard-coded value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

The full error LINQ throws is:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'Apple.Models.ADMIN_USER_ROLES'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

Code that produces error (on EF 4) is shown below.

```
var userID = 1;
List<ADMIN_ROLE> roles = db.ADMIN_ROLES.Where(r => 
                         db.ADMIN_USER_ROLES.Any(ur => 
                              ur.ID_USER == userID && ur.ID_ROLE == r.ID)).ToList();
```

This error doesn't happen in LINQPad or in my other (EF 5) project.

Hardcoding the value **1** in the query instead of userID, also, doesn't show any errors.

Project was copied from another PC, where it **works**. 
Refactoring the splitting the linq into two queries would work, but I can't do that.

Does anyone know what causes this, so I avoid any refactoring.

**UPDATE 1**: This happens only in the nested queries, otherwise it works. See Mahyar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are insisting on working on IQueryables you can use the LINQ below

```
var userRoles = db.ADMIN_USER_ROLES.Where(ur => ur.ID_USER == userID);
var rols = (from r in db.ADMIN_ROLES
where (from ur in userRoles select ur.ID_ROLE).Contains(r.ID)
select r).ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, this does work. Another symptom I forgot to mention that it doesn't work only in nested queries. Otherwise one such as yours, without nesting, works. Do you know the cause maybe?

Comment: You can find the reason [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c109a5bc-6797-47ae-83c6-b00161c4cad6/only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-types-are-supported-in-this-context-entity-framework?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your issue will be fixed by adding a `ToList` or `.AsEnumerable()` method, like this:

```
db.ADMIN_ROLES.ToList().Where
```

Or:

```
db.ADMIN_USER_ROLES.ToList()
```

With `.ToList()` after data is loaded, any further operation (such as select) is performed using Linq to Objects, on the data already in memory.

Comment: It probably would but I don't want to refactor because of the problems that happen only to me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @SavoPejović Probably your are trying to use a collection of objects in memory with ones in the database, this is why I suggest to use `ToList`. Probably
in the other project they are both in the same repository, this could be the reason that it works there. BTW, this couldn't be considered as refactor IMO.

Comment: What do you mean by same repository?

Comment: @SavoPejović I mean, probably they are both already in memory, or they are both in database.

Comment: Intellisense says that extension methods (where & any) return IQueryable so I think they are both in db.